# Access two elements of NSArray at a time

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

I am using an `NSMutableArray` to hold some objects, and I need to access the element at `i` and the element at `i+1` in the same line. Also, is there any way to access the `NSMutableArray`'s length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < [arry count]; i++)
{
  [arry objectAtIndex:i];
  [arry objectAtIndex:i+1];
}
```

As for your second question, yes, use the selector `count`. I think you need to spend some time with the `NSMutableArray` documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't know what method accessed the length of the array

Comment: Here is the docs:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: And don't forget that it is substantially an NSArray: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArray

Answer (score 2):

You have access to all of NSArray's methods, including `objectAtIndex:`, and `count`. Then you need a traditional c loop:

```
int count = [myArray count] - 1; // -1 so we don't exceed bounds by getting i+1 on last element
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  id thisElement = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
  id theNextElem = [myArray objectAtIndex:i+1];
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I want to document here that user @Stream suggested a very good edit to this post, and it was erroneously rejected. I incorporated the critical part of his edit, going about it in a slightly different way. It's worth mentioning in case Stream or the moderator sees this comment, that the code Stream suggested was indeed valid (commas *are* allowed in each section of a for loop: for(int i=0,int j=0; ...)

Comment: The `-1` after count is incorrect. The count method returns the number of elements, and indexes are 0 based. Therefore, if the loop only runs when `i` is less than the count, and therefore within the bounds of the indexes of this array.

Comment: @Linuxios keep in mind, we are accessing objectAtIndex:`i+1`, that's the motivation for only iterating to the second-to-last element. :-)

Comment: [The suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/310453) was partially rejected simply because suggested edits are discouraged from changing code. Depending on the scope of the problem with the code, commenting or posting a correct answer are better options.

Comment: Fair, a comment would have been great, since I am of the opinion that *without the -1 this is buggy code*.

Comment: @JoshCaswell; I was the one who rejected it and I stand by it. It would make the code be full of syntax and logic errors not present in the original version.

Comment: Syntax errors? I copied it from the suggestion and ran it on my machine. Commas are allowed there!

Comment: @Linux: You were one of two. I actually thought that I was also one of the two, but I was scooped apparently. It's moot now, anyways.

Comment: If I'm wrong about the syntax, I'd like to be convinced of it. @Linuxios, are you talking about the comma?

Comment: @ctrahey: And you introduced a logic bug. You used `=` where you wanted `==`. And are you sure it worked? there is a comma operator, but if that worked, it probably shouldn't have. Did you run the program?

Comment: @Linuxios, yes I ran it, and yes, the `=` is what I want. The code, as it stands in my answer presently, is accurate, runnable, and logically appropriate. I'm so confused as to why you would even think I wanted `==`... and I hope you also understand why we are comparing against count-1. It's important if you are moderating this community that you understand why this code is appropriate.

Comment: @ctrahey: In that case, I am sorry (but not a mod, just a normal user with edit privileges). Can you then explain the use of `=` there? Feel free to give the edit again, I'll give it an approve.

Comment: I made a chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13590/compound-for-loop-construct

Comment: For the curious, the motive behind using a previously-assign int in the comparison portion of the loop (`int count = [myArray count];for(int i = 0; i<count;i++){`) is to reduce calls to methods which may take more cycles than necessary (such as `[myArray count]`) when all you *really* need is to compare two ints. It's more efficient this way. Additionally, we made count be `-=1` because inside the loop we are accessing not just `index:i`, but also `index:i+1`, which if count == length, would cause array out-of-bounds exception.